# MailComposeView dismisses another view controllers from Navigation Stack

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I have a storyboard application with 5 items in Tabbar. I am using separate navigation controllers for each tab item.

When I select 4th item in Tabbar, the navigation controller loads with initial view controller. Then I pushed 2 more controllers into this. The 3rd view controller in my navigation stack contains a button, which allow me to send email. So that when I click on the button I am presenting a "MFMailComposeViewController" with following code.

```
if([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]) {
    MFMailComposeViewController *mailCont = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    mailCont.mailComposeDelegate = self;
    [mailCont setToRecipients:[NSArray arrayWithObject:self.lblEmail.text]];
    [mailCont setSubject:@"Your email"];
    [mailCont setMessageBody:@"Your message" isHTML:NO];

    [self presentViewController:mailCont animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Then in my "didFinishWithResult" delegate, I am dismissing the presented mail compose view. But it dismisses additional 2 view controllers from my navigation stack and app lands in root view of the navigation controller.

I have tried various methods to dismiss the presented mail compose view.
See the code snippet below.

```
- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController*)controller didFinishWithResult:   (MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError*)error
{
    //... 1st approach ...
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

    //... 2nd approach ...
    [controller dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

    //... 3rd approach ...
    [self.presentedViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Please help me, I am sitting with this for many hours.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: All 3 approach worked for me.

Comment: Which of your view controllers are the above code snippets in?

Comment: The 3rd view controller

Comment: @CarouselMin : Its working for me too. But it dismisses my view controllers in navigation controller

Comment: @AnoojVM, please download the [sample project](https://www.dropbox.com/s/mzg17f0gerhojnh/TabBarMailCompose.zip?dl=0) I just wrote.

Comment: @CarouselMin My controllers in stack are  

"<Controller1: 0xbeadbe0>",
    "<Controller2: 0x15c49b80>",
    "<Controller3: 0xccc4c00>" 

SELF === Controller3: 0xccc4c00>

PRESENTTED===<MFMailComposeViewController: 0x16a3e780>

I saw your code, which looks fine. But i implemented the same, which is not working for me. Strange.

Comment: What happens if you push the mail composer, rather than modal presentation?

Comment: @AnoojVM,what I would recommend is to log your navigation stack at some break points, and see what controllers are in the stack at different time.

Comment: @CarouselMin : I have logged the stack before presenting the mail compose view, then before dismissing the mail compose view, and after dismissing the mail compose view.

In all 3 cases, same result, I can see the controllers in stack. But after dismissing mail view, application lands in initial view controller in stack.

Comment: Try log it in viewWillDisappear of self controller and viewwillAppear of initial controller

Comment: @CarouselMin The viewWillDisappear of self controller is called just after the "dismiss" mail compose view statement.

But in stack, I can see all 3 controllers.

Comment: yes, that's expected, sorry, I don't know what's the problem.

Comment: @CarouselMin : and one more thing, the viewDidLoad of first view controller is called after dismissal of mail compose view.

Really confusing :-(

Comment: No, it shouldn't be called, something is wrong. Try to log stack in viewdidload of first view controller.

Comment: @CarouselMin : There stack contains only first view controller.